# Long distance relationship: flying every week to the UK

Tags: uk, europe, repeat-visits, brazilian-citizens

I'm Brazilian and my boyfriend is French, but currently living in the UK. I will soon be moving to Paris (studies) so the travels will be less expensive and more frequent. We were planning on visiting each other every weekend, with me going one week and him another.

However, I do not hold a European passport and because I would have to fly every other week, I'm afraid I would be turned down and could never return to the UK. Any suggestions on how to avoid it?

I do not plan on moving there even after I finish my studies. My boyfriend doesn't even plan to continue studying in the UK.

Comment: "_Any suggestions on how to avoid it?_" - don't fly so often.

Comment: The simplest thing is for him to always visit you.

Comment: You could apply for a standard visitor visa in which you explain your situation, provide your current financials including your job in Paris, and prove that you have interests in Paris which make it so you're not planning on secretly living in the UK. That would answer some of the border agent's questions, who is definitely going to find it suspicious that you visit twice per month, or even once per month.
But YMMV, I really don't know whether they will accept such a situation.

Comment: So why would you not use the Eurostar and fly into London from Paris ? I can guarantee you if you travel so frequently to London from Paris you will be stopped at the border, questioned and maybe refused entry. If you still want to go ahead and do it, take the Eurostar so you will be refused entry in Paris and go back home, rather than sit in the glass cage at Heathrow airport  and then sent back.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique How an apllication (which you give away and never see again) would answer border officer's questions? They don't see your application.

Comment: @Neusser you could tell the border guard you applied for a visa for this reason instead of travelling visa free, that could help you at the border. I still think it's risky though, better him coming to Paris once or twice a month.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see a problem with this.  Apply for a visa and if asked, state that you want to go every second weekend for a couple of days.  You do have an EU visa and you do have attachments to France via your educational commitments.

Comment: Assuming the boyfriend doesn't live in London, then that probably puts the Eurostar out of the question. LA Femme Cosmiques suggestion is probably the best and if it provides you with something like a 1 year multiple entry visa, then solves your problems, for a year at least.

Comment: @OliverHouston exactly. Then OP's intentions, and all the proof needed to back up their claims (that they will return, that they're doing things above the book, that their frequent and successive visits to the UK are NOT secretely living there) are a matter of record, which saves OP from having to worry every 2 weeks about being turned away - and being turned away would result in a lot more future scrutiny. An entry clearance protects against that.

Comment: Have you lived with your boyfriend for at least two years at some point in the past?  If so, you should be able to qualify to enter the UK under the EU right of freedom of movement.  If you do, you will get an EEA family permit, which is free of charge and allows you to enter the UK freely as long as your boyfriend is either in the UK already or traveling with you.

Comment: @Neusser apparently border officers do give a good deal of deference to existing visas, so I presume they do actually get some information about the application from their systems when they scan the traveler's passport or visa.

Comment: You could get the train too if flying isn’t feasible.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm afraid I would be turned down and could never return to the UK

Any time someone pronounces that phrase in relation to UK immigration, a magical piece of advice inevitably pops up here on Travel.SE:

> **Apply for an entry clearance/Standard Visitor Visa**

Making an application for a UK visa is not particularly difficult in your circumstances as you're a non-visa national who is resident in an EU country and who was formerly a UK resident. It will cost you 90 pounds to apply and a trip to the UK consulate, but it will be worth the effort. Once you arrive at the UK border with a previously issued entry clearance, the immigration procedures will be mostly a formality as the Immigration Officer will be a lot more confident that he's dealing with a genuine visitor rather than someone trying to build up a life in the UK without going through the appropriate channels.

Note that the duration of your visits would still have to be sensible in regards to your status as a student, but going every second weekend is definitely more than reasonable.